# How to read branches in pyroot and make plots?

Tags: python, branch, pyroot

I'm completely new to Python and pyroot, and I want to write a small script in pyroot as a just practice. My root file has a subdirectory in which you can find a few trees some of which contains a few branches. What I am trying to do is making plots of variables.Let's say branches are x,y,z in tree1 and want to make plot of x vs z. example.root-->sub_dir-->tree3,tree2,tree1-->x,y,z etc

Here is what I have so far but does not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ROOT
c1=ROOT.TCanvas("mycanvas","mycanvas",600,600)
c1.SetGrid( )
f=ROOT.TFile("example.root/sub_dir")
t=f.Get("tree1")
t.Draw("x:z")
```

Hope I am able to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think `example.root/sub_dir` isn't a `TFile` (it is a directory in a file).

So I would change it to

```
f=ROOT.TFile("example.root")
t=f.Get("subdir/tree1")
```

which works for me.